# Случайная фраза PHP

Tags: php

Есть несколько HTML строк:

```
<div>ПРИВЕТ</div>
<div>Пока</div>
<div>Добрый день</div>
```

Как с помощью PHP выводить каждый раз случайную строку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Arr = array(
    'Hello',
    'Good day!',
    'Bye Bye'
);

echo $Arr[rand(0, sizeof($Arr)-1)];
echo $Arr[array_rand($Arr)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$hello=array('ПРИВЕТ','Пока','Добрый день');
echo $hello[rand()%3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Случайные фразы загоняем в массив и выводим их с помощью http://www.php.su/functions/?mt-rand